# SAP: Problem connecting BAS to CF for Odata service

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-business-application-studio

I am trying to connect to my cloud foundry abap environment, where I "created" and  deployed an Odata Service based on that course: https://open.sap.com/courses/fiori-ea1/items/4IKfdIpzsrvKOH5sYIIid3

I dont know why, but in my Business application studio (BAS) environment where I configure my access to a SAP System, it does not find my ABAP environment (where I hosted my Odata service):

I previously logged in in the terminal to cloud foundry via: `cf login -a "https://url-to-cf-env..."`, but it still doesnt find it..
[image: https://open.sap.com/courses/fiori-ea1/items/4IKfdIpzsrvKOH5sYIIid3]

In the cloud cockpit, I have created two instances in dev space:
[image]

I also created a service key for eclipse to create the odata service..
**The thing that I am wondering about is, I have access to an entity of my odata service in the browser, I get the data returned in xml.
But I get 401: unauthorized with Postman... and I am wondering why?**

[image: Browser]
[image: Postman]

My request header for the odata airline entity:
[image]

I'm not sure if I need it, but my cloud destination config is as follows:
[image]
WebIDEUsage: `odata_abap,ui5_execute_abap,dev_abap,odata_cloud`

Comment: Does this https://answers.sap.com/answers/13740145/view.html also apply to you?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann thanks I think that could actually solve the problem. But my problem now is, I apparently used all my quotas from the cloud and deleted previous instances, and I can't create new instances for now to test it :(

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann I just created new cloud environment and reacreated all services and tried cf login --sso option but that was just different login option, I could log into the cloud but I do not get any services shown...